# Google maps PlaceDetails in different language than English

Tags: angularjs, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

i wanted to ask you if there is a way to get the google maps place details  in a different language than English. I use AngularJs and i created a directive in which i perform the below steps:

1. User types in an autocomplete field
2. I get the results, i parse them and then I try to get the details like this:

`service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(theMap.map);
service.getDetails({
                        placeId: placeId,
                        key: googleMapsAPIKey,
                        language: 'el'
                    }, function(place) {
myLangAddressComponents = place.address_components;
});`

The problem is that **myLangAddressComponents** information is still in English.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the documents regarding [**Optional Parameters: language**](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/details#PlaceDetailsRequests),

> The language code, indicating in which language the results should be returned, if possible. Note that some fields may **not be available** in the requested language. See the list of supported languages and their codes. Note that we often update supported languages so this list may not be exhaustive.

I think that there is no problem in your code, it is just not yet available in the requested language. I hope this clear some issues you've encountered. :)

Answer (score 0):

Keep in your mind that you are passing the map instance in the PlacesService. As I saw from experimenting if the map is localized in el then the results would be also in el.